# Problems hosting a WPF control in a windows form

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, winforms

I have a **Winform** application and want to to use **WPF** inside this application. I add a WPF user control to my VS project. Then I take a **ElementHost** control from the toolbox and put it on a form. After that I build the solution.

The problem is now, when I want to embed the WPF control with "**Edit Host Content**" into the ElementHost controlI get the message "This ElementHost is currently not hosting any editable content....." What's wrong? How can I achieve (in VS) that the ElementHost control knows/references/hosts my WPF control ?

Comment: The error message tells you what to do.  Use the combo box to select the control first.